# How can I upload translated descriptions of an android app to the developer console?

Tags: android, upload, translation

I have made an Android App and translated the description (which appears on the Play Store) of the app in many languages.

How can I upload the descriptions directly to the developer console ?

EDIT :
The fact is :
For each language translation you want to add to an app as public description, you have to copy - paste. 
We are talking about 42 languages, "description" + "what's new" sections.
so about 82 copy - paste...

I would like to get a way to simplify these actions.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean from the command line?

Comment: Well, I have about 40 descriptions XML files. And I would lik to find a way to click on some button or execute some command line to upload them directly to the Google Play developer Console... I edited the question

Comment: If it was only 82 copy-paste, I'm sure you could have gotten it done long before now with just the manual approach.

Comment: You could try building your own tool with a Chrome extension or a GreaseMonkey script that does the clicking for you.

Comment: Jay Snayder : yep, but I have to to it for 30 apps... so 30 * 82 copy paste. I just don't want to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent a request to Google, and they answered me this :

> Hi,
>
> Thank you for your note. We understand you wish to upload localized
>   descriptions in bulk. Unfortunately we do not currently support this
>   functionality. We really appreciate your thoughtful feedback, and
>   we'll be sure to take your thoughts into consideration as we work to
>   improve Google Play.
>
> If we can assist you further, please let us know.
>
> Regards, The Google Play Team

I'm not going any further.
I already wasted too much time.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Google Play does not offer any API that allows you to upload descriptions, screenshots, updated APKs etc.

At best, you could spend a fair amount of time figuring out the various requests they use to insert data into the server, and emulate them from a small Java program. However, this probably isn't worth the trouble, as it would take really long to figure out the data in and the format of the various POST and GET requests.